# Can't get last version of NPM working

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to update npm to latest version, since I'm using the 1.4.28.
Using:

```
npm update -g npm
```

I get the following output:

```
npm@1.3.26 C:\Users\ck\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm-check-updates\node_modules\npm
npm@2.1.5 C:\Users\ck\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\npm
```

and then running

```
npm -v
```

I can see that I'm still using the 1.4.28; I can't understand the output I got after trying to update, since it is talking about 1.3.26 and 2.1.5, but I have installed 1.4.28??

I'm on windows and I've already tried to uninstall and reinstall node;

Comment: The `npm` installations you're updated are dependencies of other modules -- `npm-check-updates` and `ember-cli`. Those modules will likely have limitations on what versions of `npm` they support.

Comment: ok, thanks fro clarifing this; but why npm update -g npm does not update the version I'm using from 1.4.28 to 2.1.0? And from where it comes from version 1.4.28?

Comment: For Windows, `npm` typically isn't placed under the global [`root`](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-root.html) where it can manage itself. It's usually under `Program Files` instead. You can check this with `npm -g root` and `gcm npm | select source` (PowerShell).

Comment: Thanks this solved the issue: npm (1.4.28) was installed in c:\programs\nodejs while the npm root was somewhere else

Comment: So, how did you actually update npm? I'm in that same situation where updating npm or re-installing node leaves me at 1.4.28; my npm root is "C:\Windows\system32\node_modules" and my npm -g root is "C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules", but I'm not clear on what to do with that info.

Answer (score 11):

**from this page:https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting**

```
on windows:
            Option 1:
              edit your Windows installation's PATH to put C:\Users\<username>\AppDa\Roaming\npm before
     C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs. Remember that you'll need to restart cmd.exe (and potentially restart Windows) when you make changes to PATH or how npm is installed.

            Option 2: remove both of before updating
                C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\npm
                C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\npm.cmd

            Option 3: navigate to C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs 
               with cmd.exe and then run the installation without -g:
               npm install npm

on linux:
npm install -g npm@latest
```

Comment: For option 3 on Windows - run the cmd as administrator.

Answer (score 2):

In order to install the latest npm, you'll run:

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

You'll also need to ensure that if you have multiple `npm` commands installed, you are using the latest (rather than the original `npm` installed with `node`).

Try this:

```
which -a npm
```

Based on your findings from the above command, you may need to adjust your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: This is very confusing, does it nest an installation of npm within npm, or does it really globally update the installation of npm in the OS? Anyway, I get `/usr/local/lib/iojs-v3.3.1-linux-x64/bin/npm -> /usr/local/lib/iojs-v3.3.1-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
npm@2.14.3 /usr/local/lib/iojs-v3.3.1-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm
`. Maybe it doesn't play well with having io.js installed and upgraded. Is it only me? :)

Comment: Do you have /usr/local/lib/iojs-v3.3.1-linux-x64/bin in your `$PATH`?

Comment: Nope. [I posted a separate question for it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32607923/is-io-js-hijacking-npms-global)

Answer (score 1):

Finally able to update npm. A bit uncooperative guy whew! Tried to install / update nom first `npm install -g nom@latest` then `npm install -g npm@latest` on admin level console / windows command.

From 1.4.28 to 2.1.7

Weird but hey it works for me!

Comment: Is the first install -g *nom*@latest intentional, or a typo. Seems like nom is really a thing, a jquery implementation for the server-side, but i doubt you meant that here.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you may need to check both your user path and system path. If `C:\Program Files\nodejs\;` appears in system path and `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm`, then npm will refer to the version in `C:\Program Files\nodejs\;`. This was the problem for me, and was resolved by putting `C:\Program Files\nodejs\;` at the end of the user path and removing it from the system path. Don't forget to restart the terminal after changing the path. Though useful in helping me to find the problem, none of baaroz's solutions worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted this folder C:\Users<username>\AppDa\Roaming\npm and C:\Users<username>\AppDa\Roaming\npm-cache and the did the node.js install and was able to have the updated version of npm