# is io.js hijacking npm's global?

Tags: node.js, npm, iojs

Having installed io.js aside node.js, I notice the following oddity trying to upgrade node-gyp. When trying out `npm install -g node-gyp` I get the following at the top of the output:

```
/usr/local/lib/iojs-v3.3.1-linux-x64/bin/node-gyp -> /usr/local/lib/iojs-v3.3.1-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js
node-gyp@3.0.3 /usr/local/lib/iojs-v3.3.1-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/node-gyp
```

I am a bit concerned that io.js installation, or the [hack used for upgrading it](https://github.com/jekrb/iojs-update), have somehow altered the way npm works with global package installation. I similarly get references to iojs also with other npm commands, e.g. with `npm install -g npm@latest`, so it may seem like npm is now either giving io.js special care with some unique log messages, or *not installing for node.js but rather only for iojs*.

- Do node.js and io.js access the same npm global depo?
- Otherwise, does io.js hijack the `-g` destination? in which case, what might be the safest way to revert npm to work with the node.js global depo, short of purging npm altogether?

Looks like `npm install -g` only install to an io.js path on my system now...

Comment: iojs and nodejs have merged their codebase into new release v4.0.0    they have joined forces so no need to run iojs

Comment: doesn't seem to look like that on https://iojs.org/en/...